# irrationality or rationality of $\log(\log(2))$.

Tags: calculus, irrational-numbers

I know the standard proof that $\log_{10}(2)$ is irrational. Can we prove irrationality of  $\log_{10}(\log_{10}(2))$ using, somehow, similar methods?

Comment: What standard proof are you referring to?

Comment: If $log_{10}(2)=\frac{m}{n}$ then $2^n=10^m$ which is impossible.

Comment: Let:
$$log_{10}(log_{10}2)=-\frac{m}{n}$$
where $m,n\in Z^{+}$, $m<n$ (these properties are observed from the graph $y=log_{10}(x)$) and $gcd(m,n)=1$ 
$$\Rightarrow log_{10}2=10^{-\frac{m}{n}}$$
$$\Rightarrow (log_210)^{n}=10^{m}$$ It seems almost a dead end to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we can't. But it can be done with the use of more hardcore methods. If $\log_{10}(\log_{10}2)$ were rational, that would make $\log_{10}2$ a rational power of 10, and hence an *algebraic* number, which in turn would violate the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).